# How does temperature affect ionic Ca in milk

Tags: titration, precipitation

I’m doing an investigation on the effects of temperature on ionic calcium content in milk through a classic EDTA titration method and have a few questions:
— what is the scientific theory behind the reason why ionic Ca decreases from increased temperature? (with respect to how it is measured through EDTA chelation)
— does this permanently affect Ca content
— how relevant is this with regard to health (e.g. does precipitated Ca have health benefits?)

Comment: Would you mind showing your results? How does the calcium concentration change and what is the exact titration procedure?

Comment: I mean what temp. are you talking about? What is the indicator etc?

Comment: Asking for answers and not providing details, purpose or background of questions are contradictory decisions.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74135/does-changing-edta-concentrations-affect-the-amount-of-calcium-ions-in-milk